# Not able to delete the S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to delete the S3 bucket in Region 1, but I'm unable to and in AWS console, I was able to see the following issue:

`POST https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/proxy 404 (Not Found)`

Moreover, I was not able to view the region against that particular S3 bucket. Please post your suggestions on this. But I tried creating the same bucket in another region and deleted the same, and I was able to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Actually that bucket doesn't exist in that location. But only the name of the bucket is there in that location. so if we can delete and create the stack again. It won't throw any error.